Quartz Dark Theme in SAP Solution Manager not selectable
SAPUI5 Distribution 1.71.59 (built at 2023-09-13T10:25)
OpenUI5 Version 1.71.59 (built at 2023-09-11T08:32:46Z)
Above are our Versions. We aren't able to select the Quartz Dark Theme in the Solution Manager. Every Note I found is either not includable or simply obsolete. Has anyone ever done that and can provide a Step-By-Step Guide for this? There are 64 Notes with the tag "FIORI_3_DARK", but we can't get it to work and it gets pretty frustrating.
I used guides like this one from LinkedIn, but the notes are not includable. And I can't find any, that are and will make it work. Maybe we need to do some Customizing?

For this kind of problem, I think you'd better contact the SAP Support.
